# Is it possible to send attachment via email using Powershell without SMTP?

Tags: powershell, office365, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Is it possible to send attachment via email using Powershell without SMTP.

I would need to send the SharePoint list data as a csv attachment via email to users.

Comment: "without SMTP" - so, you want to send an email, but you don't want to send email?

Comment: :) @MathiasR.Jessen...if u refer my question i have mentioned about SharePoint. Will there be any other way like PowerShell command "Send-PnPMail " with attachment and CC.

Comment: I don't know about SharePoint, but maybe you could download the item and [submit to Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)?